# Show an ellipsis (or something) where comments are not contiguous

Tags: feature-request, comments

It appears the site only shows the most popular comments on a post when there are lots of comments. Reading sequentially through those can sometimes give users the wrong meaning when that context is missing.

Could we get an ellipsis or something that indicates that more comments should appear *within* the conversation? You could also have them be links that do the same as the "Show X more comments" link at the end.

*Update* I'll just add that having this would actually **increase performance** in my case by reducing the number of times I click the "Show X more comments" link since the absence of the ellipsis would show me that I'm reading everything there is within that section of the conversation. Right now I can't trust it, so I click the link pretty much every time.

Comment: In StackOverflowExtra userscript this is signaled with a darker top border of the first comment after the hidden ones, and the bottom one if there are hidden comments bellow the last visible comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrrmH.jpg

Comment: I like this idea, it would help to have a visual cue indicating where the break is.

Comment: I guess your update depends on whether SE loads all the comments prior to rendering the page (very little benefit) or does not (implying some sort of "load me" flag is persisted in the comments table)

Comment: @Ben I can see a separate request is being made when the link is clicked. So if I can get what I need knowing that I have the full context for the section of comments that I'm reading, then I can avoid clicking that link and avoid making that request. That's the performance gain I'm referring to.

Comment: [Cross-site dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24490/can-we-get-an-indication-comments-are-hidden-between-the-comments), [meta-tag:status-declined].